# SwiftUI: NavigationLink and ScrollView drag gesture colliding

Tags: scrollview, swiftui, navigationview, navigationlink

I'm trying to implement a `UICollectionView` like `View` in SwiftUI which basically works fine. But when I scroll/drag inside the scroll view to scroll down, the tap is recognized on the `NavigationLink` and then navigating to the detail view, even if I just wanted to scroll down.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Additional info: The whole `NavigationView` is opened from a `.sheet` from another view (as you might notice in the screenshot). I tried adding a "manual" link by setting the `tag` property on the link and setting the tag within a `TapGesture`, but this doesn't work either.

Here is a short example where the error can be reproduced. Scrolling down will activate a tap on one of the white rectangles.

[View before drag gesture on scroll view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEfA5.png)

[View during drag gesture, tap is already recognized on NavigationLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF71G.png)

[Navigation view pushes to detail view after drag gesture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80yZn.png)

```swift
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0..<6) { i in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail")) {
                            Rectangle()
                                .background(Color.red)
                                .frame(width: 365, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Items")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code works as expected as a stand-alone view, just not presented in a sheet. This most likely means that Apple didn't expect a `NavigationView` to be used within `.sheet()`, and didn't test for weird effects like this. I'd file feedback (http://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

Comment: Definitely looks like a major oversight on Apples side. I've been trying to cancel the navigation link when a drag starts by doing `.highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())` on the NavigationLink and this works but it also hijacks the scrollviews drag :/

Comment: Thanks everybody, I filed a feedback at Apple

Comment: I think the issue is that the SwiftUI ScrollView doesn't delay it's content touches the way UIKit does: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619398-delayscontenttouches